# Overlaying content on a progressbar

Tags: css, html

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.progress {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div>some header content</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="overlay">
      <span>some stuff</span>
      <input/>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/PlayStation_button_X.svg"/>
    </div>
    <progress class="progress"></progess>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="overlay">
      <span>some stuff</span>
      <input/>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/PlayStation_button_X.svg"/>
    </div>
    <progress class="progress"></progess>
  </li>
</ul>
<div>some footer content</div>
```

So what I'm trying to do is have the background of a list element show the progress of that list item processing. What you could do is use a 1x1 pixel image of your chosen color and set it as the background image. Then on progress updates, set the background-width equal to that progress value.

HTML5 now has a progressbar element so I was wondering how hard it would be to implement the same style using that. So far this is the best I've got and it's extremely finicky. Is there actually an easy way to do something like this that I'm overlooking? If not it seems like in this scenario I'm better off doing it the old fashioned way described above.

Here's an example of what the end goal would be similar to.

```js
let bgSize = 0;
function increaseWidth() {
  bgSize++;
  let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundSize = bgSize + '% 100%';
  }
  if(bgSize < 100) {
    setTimeout(increaseWidth, 500);
  }
}
setTimeout(increaseWidth, 500);
```

```css
li {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/xnhGEBj.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div>some header content</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>some stuff</span>
        <input/>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/PlayStation_button_X.svg"/>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>some stuff</span>
        <input/>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/PlayStation_button_X.svg"/>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div>some footer content</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve is not clear

Comment: I've added an example of what the goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

JS

```
let bgSize = 0;
let timer = null;

function increaseProgressBar () {
  bgSize++;

  const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('progress');

  for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].value = bgSize;
  }

  if(bgSize < 100) {
    timer = setTimeout(increaseProgressBar, 500);
  }else{
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
  }
}

timer = setTimeout(increaseProgressBar, 500);
```

CSS

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  li {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;

    progress {
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }

    progress[value] {
      appearance: none;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
      -webkit-appearance: none;

      &::-webkit-progress-bar {
        background-color: #fff;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div>some header content</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>some stuff</span>
    <input/>
    <progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/PlayStation_button_X.svg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>some stuff</span>
    <input/>
    <progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/PlayStation_button_X.svg"/>
  </li>
</ul>
<div>some footer content</div>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/kieran/pen/BPwGpJ)

Comment: That's pretty nice, I couldn't get this to work for the life of me.

Comment: Good :) let me know if you need help with anything else